# Update more then one mysqli query at once

Tags: php, mysql, sql

**Multiple table/row/column update in single query**

I would like to short up my code because i have few user and my server hang up when there are many user. Also let me know if its time saving if i use them in single query or if its fine to use multiple query then i am happy with it

**This is my tax table**

```
id | time       | tax1 | tax2 | tax3
1  | 1469856318 | 1    | 2    | 6 
2  | 1469856318 | 5    | 1    | 1 
3  | 1469856318 | 6    | 8    | 5 
4  | 1469856318 | 2    | 7    | 7 
5  | 1469856318 | 1    | 1    | 2
```

I am using this steps but sometimes there are so many row and column.

```
$u0 = "UPDATE tax SET time='$ms', tax1='$tax1' WHERE id = 1";
$u1 = "UPDATE tax SET time='$ms', tax2='$tax2' WHERE id = 2";
$u2 = "UPDATE tax SET time='$ms', tax3='$tax3' WHERE id = 3";
```

I would love to see if it is possible to do this in one query

**Another thing**

If it is possible to update two different tables in a single query

```
$u0 = "UPDATE tax SET time='$ms', tax1='$tax1' WHERE id = 1";
$u1 = "UPDATE tax SET time='$ms', tax2='$tax2' WHERE id = 2";
$u2 = "UPDATE tax SET time='$ms', tax3='$tax3' WHERE id = 3";
$u4 = "UPDATE tax1 SET tax2='$tax2' WHERE id = 5";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional logic to update a single table:

```
UPDATE tax
    SET time = '$ms',
        tax1 = (CASE WHEN id = 1 THEN '$tax1' ELSE tax1 END),
        tax2 = (CASE WHEN id = 2 THEN '$tax2' ELSE tax2 END),
        tax3 = (CASE WHEN id = 3 THEN '$tax3' ELSE tax3 END)
    WHERE id IN (1, 2, 3);
```

I would recommend updating each query independently.

Comment: i will give it a try

Comment: this worked fine for one table. if i am only updating **tax1**

Comment: @thepak . . . I missed that those are different columns you are updating.  I fixed the answer.